# How to send whatsapp message using Twilio asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, twilio, whatsapp

**Hi,**

I want to be able to send Whatsapp messages using Twilio, but I need it to be asynchronously. Here is my code:

```
public async void EnvioWhatsapp(string TelefonoCelular)
{
    const string accountSid = "mySid";
    const string authToken = "myToken";

    TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

    var message = MessageResource.Create
        (
                body: "Hola mundo!",
                from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+myNumber"),
                to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+clientNumber")
        );
}
```

In my code `EnvioWhatsapp` is underlined in green with the message:

"This async method lacks await operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the await operator to await non-blocking API calls..."

I have tried inserting `await` in multiple areas of the method but nothing works so far, and yes I have been looking at the Twilio api docs, but I cannot find a way to make the call asynchronously.

Thank you, and sorry for the Spanish nomenclature, I know it makes it a little harder to read the code.

Comment: Which part exactly do you want to run asynchronously? You could just put that specific call into a `Task.Run` (though then you don't need to declare the method as `async void`)

Comment: @UnholySheep What part exactly? I dare say ´MessageResource.Create´ since that is the function I think I will be waiting for from Twilio.

Comment: I think OP wants make use of IO threads instead. Use REST API instead - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/reference/ If it just https request - you can easily do this asynchronous.

Comment: What type of application is this in? A UI app, or ASP.NET web service, etc.?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Its a .NET Core MVC project, exclusively for having APIs that a project in Angular-Ionic will use.

Comment: Did any of this helped you?

Comment: @Stefan Sadly, no. The code works just fine, but the objective is for it to be asynchronous. I have been reading more on the Twilio api docs, it may seem that their whatsapp api may only work synchronously, but I'm still looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp-dotnet/usage-guide#asynchronous-methods) you should use `CreateAsync`.

You can either return it as `Task`, or await it. In any case try to avoid the `async void` signature. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void

Comment: Looks promising, I will give it a try first thing in the morning on Monday.

Comment: This did the job! Thank you, I must be blind because I could not find that in the docs, thank you.

Comment: no worries; we've all experienced that feeling now and then ( :